# Sending and receiving SMS via a huawei 3g Dongle E220

Tags: raspbian, gsm

I have a **Huawei E220 3G dongle**. I have set it up with my Raspberry Pi to connect to the internet by executing the sakis3g script. Now I want to send and receive SMS to and from Raspberry pi via the 3g dongle to my mobile phone.
How should i go about this. Please suggest some methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a command line utility Gammu. Check out http://wammu.eu/gammu/

Or you can follow this tutorial to interface with the modem directly to send and receive sms on your Raspberry Pi: https://web.archive.org/web/20140712150707/https://myraspberryandme.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/short-message-texting-sms-with-huawei-e220/

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this tutorial as well: [Turning the Raspberry Pi into a SMS Center using Python](http://hristoborisov.com/index.php/projects/turning-the-raspberry-pi-into-a-sms-center-using-python/)

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.