# How to setup a Pi 3 that can act as a robot to send and receive SMS and WhatsApp?

Tags: pi-3

## Requirements

- Able to send/receive sms
- Able to send/receive messages on WhatsApp

## Equipment I do have

- Pi 3
- A separate 3G/4G SIM card with its own mobile number that can be used for the Pi 3

There are plenty of resources on how to do this for Whatsapp or send out SMS using Pi. But none of these use Pi 3 and none of these resources talk about doing both at the same time.

***Updated with research***

- [Article on how to setup WhatsApp on Pi](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-control-a-raspberry-pi-using-whatsapp-1315610/2) (written in Feb 2016. No indication of Pi model. No indication of extra hardware. Uses Yowsup library)
- [Raspi SE question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/19451/55001) on how to read/write SMS (written in 2014. More likely to be not suitable for Pi 3. Indicated that a Huawei E220 3G dongle was required. Accepted answer uses Ganmu library)

What extra equipment do I need to buy and steps I need to do so that I can turn my Pi 3 into a separate programmable phone that can answer enquiries on my behalf?

The programming part for the answering of enquiries is not an issue for me. The issue for me is how do I setup the Pi 3 hardware and what programs I need to run in Raspbian in order for me to read and extract the information coming from these 2 mediums?

***Updated with remarks***

Given that my research yields possibly less up-to-date information, I was wondering if someone has already tried this for Pi 3 and made it work? With as few extra hardware as possible.

Comment: I can't see anything about your research effort.

Comment: Perhaps as you will find no difficulty in getting them to each work separately you could ask a more targeted question when that has been done?

Comment: @vaha Updated with research.

Comment: @joan I could, but I hoped to check with the community here before I embarked on trying out what I found. Just to avoid unnecessary deadends. If I don't get any response within a week, I guess I will have to try it out myself and then share what I found back here.

Comment: FWIW, the hardware revision of the Pi should be fairly irrelevant.  The OS version would generally be a lot more important, but probably not all that significant here either.  Your best bet is to just start with one of the articles you found and adjust as needed.

Answer (score -2):

Follow this link:

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/use-whatsapp-on-your-linux-desktop-with.html

Hope it helps

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it would be nice to see you give an explanation of the solution.

Comment: We're trying a [new policy in order to clean up informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538).  If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.